# Need help identifying red leafy plant

Tags: identification

I've asked many gardeners that I know what it is. I even used multiple plant identification sites, but no luck.

[image: red leafy plant]

Comment: Welcome to the site! That's in interesting plant! Where do you live? How old is the plant? Is it indoors or out?  More details are always better, especially with identification questions. You can just press the gray edit button and add them into the question. Our site's a little different from others, so I invite you to check out our [help]. [Ask] is a good starting page and will explain the reason why we ask for this information. I hope someone comes along soon and lets all of us know what this is!

Comment: Is this plant in a high light situation, or somewhere it doesn't get bright daylight?

Comment: It's in full sun everyday. It was given to me in May when it was about 3" tall. Now it's about 12-14" tall.

Comment: I just updated the photo. I didn't realize that it sprouted some flowers as of the last week or so.

Comment: It almost looks like a stunted amaranth. Can you get closeups of leaves and flowers?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely amaranth, specifically, Amaranthus 'Red Army' or 'Red Garnet' are the likeliest

[Amaranth - Red Garnet](http://www.4seasonsseeds.com.au/Amaranth-Greens-Red-Garne)

It's frost tender, younger leaves are edible, also used for medicinal purposes.

Comment: Whew...I went out to ID this when it looked so familiar and got lost down a rabbit hole, grins.  Thank you!!!